# Spacy: How to decide parameters to overfitting?

Tags: python, neural-network, nlp, spacy

For training new custom entities we can train a model using the steps mentioned here: https://spacy.io/usage/training#ner

But I want to know how to decide no of iterations, drop and batch size to overfit or underfit the model?

```
One example of loss is:
Starting training....
Losses:  {'ner': 3875.2103796127717}
Losses:  {'ner': 3091.347521599567}
Losses:  {'ner': 2811.074334355512}
Losses:  {'ner': 2235.2944185569686}
Losses:  {'ner': 2015.7072019365773}
Losses:  {'ner': 1647.0052678292357}
Losses:  {'ner': 1746.1746172501762}
Losses:  {'ner': 1350.2094295662862}
Losses:  {'ner': 1302.3405612718204}
Losses:  {'ner': 1322.3590930188122}
Losses:  {'ner': 1070.3760899125737}
Losses:  {'ner': 990.9221824283309}
Losses:  {'ner': 961.2431416302175}
Losses:  {'ner': 885.3743390914278}
Losses:  {'ner': 838.3100930655886}
Losses:  {'ner': 733.5780730531789}
Losses:  {'ner': 915.0732067395388}
Losses:  {'ner': 734.7598118888878}
Losses:  {'ner': 645.5447305966479}
Losses:  {'ner': 615.6987186405088}
Losses:  {'ner': 624.112212173154}
Losses:  {'ner': 590.4118676242763}
Losses:  {'ner': 411.8125225993247}
Losses:  {'ner': 482.4468110898493}
Losses:  {'ner': 479.08534166022685}
Training completed...
```

In the above output, the loss is decreasing and increasing. So at what point should I stop training?

Basically how to decide all the parameters for training?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the command-line train CLI, which runs an evaluation on a dev set after each iteration.

```
python -m spacy train en output_dir train.json dev.json -p ner
```

There's a built-in early stopping option (`-ne`), which detects when the model performance starts going down and stops after a certain number of iterations.

The data formats are different, though. Here's one way to convert the TRAIN_DATA-type format to the CLI training data format for NER:

```
import spacy
from spacy.gold import docs_to_json
import srsly

nlp = spacy.load('en', disable=["ner"])

TRAIN_DATA = [
    ("Who is Shaka Khan?", {"entities": [(7, 17, "PERSON")]}),
    ("I like London and Berlin.", {"entities": [(7, 13, "LOC"), (18, 24, "LOC")]}),
]

docs = []
for text, annot in TRAIN_DATA:
    doc = nlp(text)
    doc.ents = [doc.char_span(start_idx, end_idx, label=label) for start_idx, end_idx, label in annot["entities"]]
    docs.append(doc)

srsly.write_json("ent_train_data.json", [docs_to_json(docs)])
```

If your data is in one of the NER formats supported by `python -m spacy convert`, you can also convert it that way.

Comment: Can you please show me an example or any link where I can see the usage of early stopping option (-ne).

Comment: It's in the CLI documentation, but I'm not sure there's an full example anywhere. Just try it out with something like `-ne 3` and it will print messages when it stops early.